# Consistently generate line at at a specified angle as measured by user in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, aspect-ratio

Consider the simple code below that generates a straight downward sloping line in MATLAB.

```
clear, clc, close all

t = 0:0.1:1;
y = -t+1;


plot(t,y)
ax = gca
```

This is a line with slope -1, so the (acute) angle between the horizontal axis and the line is 45 degrees. Except it isn't when you measure with a protractor on your monitor.

Without changing the range of values displayed on the x and y axes or the height of the figure window, how could I ensure I would measure 45 degrees from the horizontal axis to the line if I held a protractor up to the screen?

My current approach is to change the width of the figure window. In the limit as the figure window is infinitely thin, the line x is a vertical line. Conversely, if the figure window is stretched to the edges of a monitor, it flattens out. Somewhere in the middle, the line has the angle I want. I just can't find a good way to mathematically find this point and instantiate it in code.

Edit: A slightly more generic solution for any acute angle. (I didn't test obtuse angles.)

```
clear, clc, close all

ang_deg = 70;
slope = tand(ang_deg);


t = 0:0.1:1;
y = -slope*t+1;

f = figure;
f.Position(3) = f.Position(3)*1.5;
plot(t,y)

% For a given height, change the width
ax = gca;
ax.Units = 'pixels';
ax.Position(3) = ax.Position(4)/slope;
```

Comment: Matlab does have functions to get the local screen resolution. get(0) is what I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow up your commands with a declaration that you'll be working in pixels, and then set the width to the height:

```matlab
ax.Units = 'pixels';
ax.Position(3) = ax.Position(4);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! This was going to drive me nuts all day.

Comment: This will not work for other angles, and the axis limits will stretch. The line will always be at 45 degrees.

Comment: That's true. I was just providing an answer to the question, not a general programming service. It is easy enough to generalize once you know the mechanism.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, L. Scott Johnson gave me the hammer for my nail. It was pretty trivial to generalize from there.

Comment: @UniqueWorldline: Luis’ answer is the right approach. — I was just pointing out what the limitations of this answer are.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that with

```
axis equal
```

which, according to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#buk989s-1-style),

> uses the same length for the data units along each axis.

You may want to also use

```
axis tight
```

which

> fits the axes box tightly around the data by setting the axis limits equal to the range of the data